# Change Entities name in WPF MVVM scaffolding from DevExpress

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, devexpress

How to change entities name for UserControl Header? 
I am create CodeFirst EF6 model and use scaffolding wizard from DevExpress. 
I change Entities name in NavBarControl in ViewModel for CollectionView, but how to change entites name for new opened View?

[Main problem picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0oftkx2h46az0zk/01.PNG?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you override the `GetTitleForNewEntity` method of your IncomingViewModel (derived from the `SingleObjectViewModel<Incoming,...>`):

```
protected virtual string GetTitleForNewEntity() {
    return typeof(TEntity).Name + CommonResources.Entity_New;
}
```